# YARD: documenting class methods added by an included module

Tags: ruby, module, class-method, yard

I am writing documentation for my ruby gem using [YARD](http://yardoc.org/).  In my gem, I have some code which follows this common ruby pattern where a module is included in a class, and that module not only adds instance methods but it also adds class methods:

```
module Moo
  def self.included(klass)
    klass.extend ClassMethods
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def hello
      puts "hello"
    end
  end
end

class Foo
  include Moo
end

Foo.hello  # => class method runs, printing "hello"
```

By default, YARD will generate documentation for the Foo class that looks like this:

[image: Inadequate documentation of the Foo class]

I think this documentation is **inadequate** because it does not tell the user that the `Foo.hello` method is available.  To learn about `hello`, the user has to click on `Moo` and then click on `ClassMethods`.

It would be great to have a list of all the class and instance methods of `Foo` on one page.  How can I make that happen?  Do I need to change the code, or is there a tag I can add to give YARD a hint about `ClassMethods`?

Comment: Did you try using [render](http://rubydoc.info/docs/yard/file/docs/GettingStarted.md#Rendering_Objects__render_____) on the embedded class? Don't know if it'd work like that or not.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I tried and couldn't get it to render anything.  Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since v0.8.0 you can use the [@!parse](http://rubydoc.info/docs/yard/file/docs/Tags.md#parse) directive:

```
class Foo
  include Moo
  # @!parse extend Moo::ClassMethods
end
```